# Is there any solution for remove or hide top toolbar section in flexmonster with react-native?

Tags: react-native

I trying to hide/remove toolbar section( CSV, JSON, OLAP, etc) on my app, which is using [react-native-flexmonster](https://github.com/flexmonster/react-native-flexmonster), as seen on the image below:

[image]

I tried [this](https://www.flexmonster.com/doc/customizing-toolbar/), but without success

Here is my code:

```js
<FlexmonsterReactNative.Pivot
   container= "pivot-container"
   toolbar={false}
   report = {{
       dataSource: {
         filename: "data/data.csv"
       },
       slice: {
         columns: [{
           uniqueName: "Color"
         }],
         rows: [{
           uniqueName: "Country"
         }, {
           uniqueName: "[Measures]"
         }],
         measures: [{
           uniqueName: "Price",
           format: "currency"
         }, {
           uniqueName: "Discount",
           format: "currency"
         }],
       },
       formats: [{
         name: "currency",
         currencySymbol: "$",
         currencySymbolAlign: "left",
         thousandsSeparator: ",",
         decimalPlaces: 2
       }],
       conditions: [{
         formula: "#value < 2000",
         measure: "Discount",
         format: {
           backgroundColor: "#CCFFCC",
         }
       }, {
         formula: "AND(#value > 2000, #value < 4000)",
         measure: "Discount",
         format: {
           backgroundColor: "#FFFF99",
         }
       }]
     }}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Some features provided by Flexmonster are not available in React Native while using their module due to some limitations it imposes on the execution of JavaScript.

It includes enabling/disabling the Toolbar.

Even so, it is possible to modify the module itself in the way the desired configuration is adjusted.

For example, the possibility to disable the Toolbar be achieved using the following approach:

Download the module mentioned earlier and modify the following code snippet in the way the toolbar property of the created instance is set to false: https://github.com/flexmonster/react-native-flexmonster/blob/f8d0f7fd6614c06e1a31585c8b8cbe22e3bc653e/src/index.js#L360-L371.

For example:

```
<script>
  new Flexmonster({
    container: "#pivot-container",
    componentFolder: "<https://cdn.flexmonster.com/>",
    toolbar: false,
    height: ${height},
    width: ${width},
    report: JSON.parse('${JSON.stringify(this.props.report)}')
  });
  ${this.registerEvents()}
</script>
```

Please note that in case such methods are required, the module should be downloaded and connected manually instead of installation through npm.